# Is it possible to specify by clause in for dynamically

Tags: scala

for(i<-1 to 100 by [here i want a clause which changes during the program run])

So, say, i've got a variable which is the desired gap for the current turn. I rewrote it with while loop, but is there any chance to accomplish that with for construct.

```
var gap = 1
for(i<-1 to 100 by gap)
gap+=1
```

Comment: How does gap change? In some predicable/codeable way, or is it dynamic and depending on what happens in the loop?

Comment: gap is being changed inside the for cycle each time it passes thru it depending on some conditions computed in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an answer to your actual question, following your comment:

`doSteps` takes the start and end of your range, an initial value for the computation, and a block that accepts the current value of the computation, and the current index in the range, and returns the updated computation and the next index to use.

```
  def doSteps[T](start: Int, end: Int)(z: T)(f: (T, Int) => (T, Int)): T =
    {
      if (start < end) {
        val (newz, newStart) = f(z, start)
        doSteps(newStart, end)(newz)(f)
      } else
        z
    }
```

(you could easily change it to return the next `gap` - just change the recursive call to `doSteams(start + newStart)`)

Example:

```
  import scala.util.Random
  doSteps(1, 100)("a")
     { (acc, i) => print(s"$i ")
       (acc + Random.nextPrintableChar(), i + Random.nextInt(5)) }
  //> 1 4 4 8 9 10 12 15 15 17 17 21 24 25 25 29 30 32 35 36 36 40 42 46 49 53 57 
  //| 58 61 61 65 69 72 76 79 83 83 85 86 88 91 95 97
  //| res0: String = a|^on3H-]>Zh]e;R(q3pTB9BQ9Y>p.Q&~_5a?~33ze{w
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are asking , but note the following shows that the `gap` is programmable:

```
scala> for (gap <- 1 to 5) {
     | for (i <- 1 to 100 by gap) {
     |    if (i % 10 == 0) println(s"gap: $gap i: $i") } }
gap: 1 i: 10
gap: 1 i: 20
gap: 1 i: 30
gap: 1 i: 40
gap: 1 i: 50
gap: 1 i: 60
gap: 1 i: 70
gap: 1 i: 80
gap: 1 i: 90
gap: 1 i: 100
gap: 3 i: 10
gap: 3 i: 40
gap: 3 i: 70
gap: 3 i: 100
```

Answer (score 0):

[`by`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Range@by(step:Int):scala.collection.immutable.Range) is just a method like any other method. And like any other method, the argument it takes doesn't have to be a literal, it can be any valid Scala expression such as a field reference, a method call, or an arbitrary much more complex expression.